# TrotiNet understanding the code

Tags: c#, trotinet

I have bit confusion on this c# code.This code is from http://trotinet.sourceforge.net/ 
Can some one make me understand ..

```
int port = 12345;
bool bUseIPv6 = false;

var Server = new TcpServer(port, bUseIPv6);
Server.Start(**TransparentProxy.CreateProxy**);
```

Transparent Proxy class :

```
public class TransparentProxy : ProxyLogic
{
    public TransparentProxy(HttpSocket clientSocket)
        : base(clientSocket) 
    {
    }

    static new public TransparentProxy CreateProxy(HttpSocket clientSocket)
    {
        return new TransparentProxy(clientSocket);
    }

    protected override void OnReceiveRequest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-> " + RequestLine + " from HTTP referer " +
            RequestHeaders.Referer);
    }

    protected override void OnReceiveResponse()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("<- " + ResponseStatusLine +
            " with HTTP Content-Length: " +
            (ResponseHeaders.ContentLength ?? 0));
    }
}
```

Since CreateProxy is static method with parameters, but the method was called from the main program without parameter. This example app works fine so I am bit confused. So, can someone make me understand :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TcpServer.Start` methods takes a delegate as a parameter.

This means that it only takes the method to execute, but executes it later in the `Start` method.

this is the signature of the `Start` method (you can find it online on github):

```
public void Start(OnNewClient onConnection)
```

and as you can see, the `OnNewClient` is a delegate:

```
public delegate AbstractProxyLogic OnNewClient(HttpSocket ss)
```

So the parameter here is a method that has the same signature as the one declared by the delegate.

You can see the source code of the `TcpServer` class here:
https://github.com/krys-g/TrotiNet/blob/master/Lib/TcpServer.cs

Comment: How can I create an instance for this TransparentProxy class ? I dont want to create a Socket because Socket will be created automatically and I need to add a Event handler which can pass to Response content to the upper level (in this case program.cs)

Answer (score 0):

The TrotiNet.TcpServer class defines the following members:

```
public delegate AbstractProxyLogic OnNewClient(HttpSocket ss);

public void Start(OnNewClient onConnection)
{
    // ...
}
```

So the TcpServer.Start() method takes a delegate parameter.

The method `TransparentProxy.CreateProxy()` matches the signature (`TransparentProxy` inherits from `AbstractProxyLogic`), so the method is not called, it is passed as delegate.

Comment: How can I create an instance for this TransparentProxy class ? I dont want to create a Socket because Socket will be created automatically and I need to add a Event handler which can pass to Response content to the upper level (in this case program.cs)